# Add value to Parent when value is added to Child MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I saw some questions and answers about adding a value to a child when add/update the parent, but my question is the opposite.
I have a model Component with a parent-child relationship:

```
public class Component
    {
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

        public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Component Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Component> Childs { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Evaluation> Evaluations { get; set; }

}
```

And i need to give a grade to each child to each user.
I have this model:

```
public class Evaluation
    {
        public virtual int EvaluationId { get; set; }

        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

        public virtual int UserCourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual UserCourse User { get; set; }

        public virtual int Grade { get; set; }
    }
```

And a view that gets a component selected and allows to choose the user and give a grade. It's only allowed to give a grade to the last child, and the grade of their parent would be the same grade of the child (the ideia is in the future to have more childs and the grade of the parent would be the sum of their grade). So i need to create a new row on the database with the same grade but with the parent id of the component selected.
I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Evaluation evaluation)
{                 

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (evaluation.Component.ParentId != 0)
        {
            var nota = new Evaluation
            {
                ComponentId = evaluation.Component.ParentId,
                UserCourseId = evaluation.UserCourseId,
                Grade = evaluation.Grade
            };
            db.Evaluations.Add(nota);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        db.Evaluations.Add(evaluation);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(evaluation);
}
```

(Note that this code can and probably is totally wrong)
How can i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After creating `nota` create a `Component`. something like this:

```
    var nota = new Evaluation
                {
                    ComponentId = evaluation.Component.ParentId,
                    UserCourseId = evaluation.UserCourseId,
                    Grade = evaluation.Grade
                };

    var component= new Component();
    component.add(nota);
    db.Components.Add(component);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

You should see your `nota` also added to `Evaluation` table because of parent-child relationship.